# Matlab: interpolation operator for multigrid methods

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have to build the following matrix:

```
 1 2 1
     1 2 1
         1 2 1
```

I tried the following:

```
 N = 8;
 full( ( spdiags(repmat([1/4,1/2,1/4], N/2-1, 1), 0:2, N/2-1, N-1) ) )
```

but the output is not what I want.

Comment: What is `N` supposed to be?

Comment: @Suever Hi. I am using a multi grid method to solve a system of linear equations and N is the dimension of the original system. But I do not think this changes anything, I just want to build that matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not *clean* but it should work anyway:

```
 N = 10;
 w(1, :) = [1, 2, 1, zeros(1, (N-1)-3)];
 for i = 1:(N/2-2)
     w(i+1, :) = [zeros(1, i*2), 1, 2, 1, zeros(1, (N-1)-(3+i*2))];
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this could be condensed a bit, but here's a solution without loops. Assuming `h` is the grid spacing and `N=1/h-1` is odd:

```
wdiag = 2*ones(N,1);
wsubsuperdiag = ones(N,1);
w = spdiags([wsubsuperdiag wdiag wsubsuperdiag],[-2 -1 0],N,(N+1)/2-1);
w = 1/2*cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) circshift(w(:,k),k-1),1:(N+1)/2-1,'uni',0));
```

Some credit to [Jon](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/197158-circshift-columns-of-array-by-different-shift-size).